# jQuery - Are there any negative effects for using multiple ready events?

Tags: jquery

I like to keep my relevant jQuery in included files. That way, when I need to work on a page, the relevant jQuery is at the top of the page.

Right now, I am including six files on a single page.  That means there are six ready events being called when the page loads.

Are there any negative side effects for using the typical ready event in every included file?

```
<-- INCLUDED FILE AAAA --->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// SOME CODE HERE

});
</script>


<-- INCLUDED FILE BBBB --->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// SOME CODE HERE

});
</script>


<-- INCLUDED FILE CCCC --->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
// SOME CODE HERE

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use multiple ready events in your code without worrying about the performance

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/multiple-document-ready

but keep in mind each `ready` event will be executed on its turn i.e. in the order they are defined or called

Comment: Your link above is great blog post!  It was very informative.  Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any. It is an usual way how to use javascript plugins.

I just use it a different way:

```
(function ($) { $(function () {
       ....
}); })(jQuery);
```

but that's the same.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's cryptic.  I've seen code like this written on King Tut's tomb.  Thanks for the try though!